# How to have the navbar-fixed-top only on one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

I have a navbar that is fixed on the homepage but considering the other pages aren't nearly as long there is no need for it to be fixed. How can I have the navbar only fixed on the homepage?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying a class to the homepage's body element and then applying the `position:fixed` declaration within the context of that class. For example: the homepage body would be `.homepage` and then set `.homepage .header {position:fixed;}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the navbar in a partial which you include in a "homepage" layout. You can then specify a layout for homepage only, defaulting to application.html.erb (or whatever) for your default layout on the rest of the pages.